# proving euclid's algorithm stops after 2k iterations

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Apparently, when initialized on $k$-bit integers $A$, $B$, Euclid's algorithm terminates after at most $2k$ iterations. This result is not immediately intuitive to me. I would appreciate help in showing this result. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to get a maximum length of steps in Euclid's algorithm (for greatest common divisor)?

Comment: Have a look at this previous Question, [Proving the number of iterations in the Euclidean algorithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483118/proving-the-number-of-iterations-in-the-euclidean-algorithm), possibly close enough to answer your questions.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to get a max length of steps.

Comment: Hint. Can you show that when you take two steps in the algorithm the bigger number is at most half of what it was?